# Win8: Registration of the app in the layout folder ... failed

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro

Noob warning. I'm really new to Windows dev tools.

I've got the latest Win8 RC installed, and got VS 2012 RC for it as well. Now I'm trying to create a Metro-style application (C#), but running into problems when executing tests from VS. The error message is:

```
Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app in the layout folder "C:\<FOLDER>" failed. 

error 0x80070005: Failed to set access rights to \\?\C:\<FOLDER>

Failed to activate Metro style unit test executor. Error : The parameter is incorrect.
```

If trying to run the unit tests from the command line using *vsttest.console.exe*, initially it failed because of an untrusted root certificate. The remedy was to add the generated .cer-file using Certutil, and after that running unit tests from the command prompt worked as expected.

However, Visual Studio still refuses to run the tests with the same error message. The **\?** in the path looks like invalid, but I don't have enough experience with VS to know whether it's normal or not. I also tried the instructions found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/06b0434f-2fbc-403f-9c44-8aa2e4b1f555) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-HK/toolsforwinapps/thread/4d399046-e7fc-4dc2-9aae-51a9e5a765da), but without any use.

Running

```
Get-WinEvent -logname Microsoft-Windows-Appx* |Select-Object -first 10|Out-GridView
```

says that "The last successful state reached was PrerequiesitesCheced", but otherwise gives me more or less the same "Failed to set access rights" error as above.

Some more background info:

- It's a shared (over vcs) project, and it runs fine on the other devs machine
- The signing certificate is not "mine", but since it runs from cmd I assume it could not be the root cause
- Tests are written using Visual Studios unit test framework, as e.g. NUnit didn't seem to work too well with Metro apps.
- The permissions in the directory should be fine, I checked that all files and dirs are owned by me, and have read/write access
- There has been another user on the laptop, and he's used VS, but the projects are not shared, and Application and signing IDs have been regenerated since. I also removed the username in my search for a solution for the problem.

Has anyone got a similar situation, and managed to fix it somehow? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm seeing this exact same issue, I posted a similar question in the MSDN forums http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-MY/winappswithcsharp/thread/06dcc04e-3300-453c-a60f-66653c225081

Comment: Another related thread on MSDN mentioned changing the "Package name" attribute under "Packaging" in Package.appxmanifest .. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We never managed to figure out a reason for this, and in order to save time I finally wiped the whole environment, and ended up re-installing windows. I'm using a dedicated machine for this, and MS has made the installation process very easy, so this was not a big deal. Problems with the pre-release I guess, because I haven't encountered a similar problem anymore, and neither has anyone else on my team.

Comment: I think it’d be better to leave the question open than to suggest doing that; I got the same problem and re-installing Windows is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: OK. I'm sorry to hear that, since I was hoping this would've been an RC-only issue, rather than something the actual released version. If you have more details on the error, or even come up with a solution, I'd be interested to hear about it.

Comment: In my case the problem turned out to be caused by Cygwin. By default Cygwin uses ACLs on files and directories it creates, to emulate the Unix permission system. If Visual Studio sees such a combination of ACLs, it erroneously deduces that the directory is a network share, and refuses to deploy the application at this location. To solve the problem, I mount my `C:` drive using Cygwin's `noacl` flag.

Comment: @SamHocevar hi Sam. I am having this same exact issue but I have no idea how to "mount my C: drive using Cygwin's noacl flag". I looked it up and so far only modified the etc\fstab to include an entry along the lines of 'c: c: binary,no-acl,user 0 0'. But that didn't work. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by changing the package name by app manifest

Answer (score 1):

In my case it turned out to be the fact that I have every folder encrypted. To run the application I had to disable encryption for the complete solution folder (and subfolder/files).

---

### How to:

First right click the folder then properties:

[image: dropdown menu]

Then clicked advanced:

[image: folder properties]

Then deselect

> Encrypt contents to secure data

[image: advanced]

At last, click apply. You are then asked where to apply the changes to. Select

> Apply changes to this folder, subfolders and files

[image: apply changes]

Now you are done.