# Can't access newly created projects in visual studio

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I'm creating a new Windows Store app in visual studio. I can't seem to run any app I create though. Even a newly created, blank app gives me the error

```
Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. error 0x80070005: Opening file from location: C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\App1\App1\bin\Debug\AppX\AppxManifest.xml failed with error: Access is denied.
. (0x80070005)  App1
```

Any ideas? I've checked the permissions of the AppxManifest.xml file and I have full control over it. I've also tried running visual studio under elevated permissions, and it still presents the same error.

Edit: Blend seems to have the same issues as visual studio, here's the output from blend:

```
Application installation failed.
Registering the application to run from layout...
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1722,9): error : DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. error 0x80070005: Opening file from location: C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\booktest\booktest\bin\Debug\AppX\AppxManifest.xml failed with error: Access is denied.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1722,9): error : . (0x80070005)
```

Comment: @Mr_Green He mentions testing elevated permissions.

Comment: Could this give you some hint?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047277/win8-registration-of-the-app-in-the-layout-folder-failed

Answer (score 18):

Give full rights to the SYSTEM account to the folder with your source code.

Comment: This solution worked for me. My new (blank) project folder was nested in a development folder for all projects. So as a result of NTFS permission inheritance, this project folder was inheriting permissions from the parent dev folder which in turn only allowed my personal user account access. So add system, give it full rights and I can now deploy. Whether or not this means the intelligence agencies of foreign governments can now steal my precious work, I dunno, but I'll worry about that when the time comes.... this is after all a "Hello World" app.

Comment: If you issue is where you have moved your app folder to maybe a Google drive or Dropbox and it wont work, then yes you need to give "SYSTEM" access to that folder with full permission.  This cost me hours of my life so thanks Jan for the solution.

Comment: you were right, in my case the folder was encrypted and so the SYSTEM account could not access it. the decryption of the folder worked

Answer (score 5):

This error also occurs if you use the subst command on Windows to map a folder path to a drive letter.

Comment: That was my issue. Any particular reason why it happen?

Comment: It usually has to do with how VS is launched, and whether it has the same security context as the user that created the subst drive letter.

Beyond that, we stopped using subst and instead just had a Local directory C:\Local\ for common paths.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that the solution folder was encrypted.  I work at a place where encryption in certain folder locations is a default.  I had to move the folder to a new location where the default did not exist.  I then went to the solution folder, right clicked on the folder and selected -> properties -> Advanced.  At the bottom is a checkbox that says "Encrypt contents to secure data".  Uncheck that and say yes to all subfolders.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your folder (**C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\App1\App1\bin\Debug\AppX\AppxManifest.xml**) security and make sure that you have full control access to that folder.

The second option is to move it to another drive, for example, **D:\New Folder**.

Comment: Both the parent folder and the manifest have full control: http://i.imgur.com/1sexd.png

Comment: Could you try to move it to another drive, for example, D:\New Folder?

Comment: Moving it to a new drive seemed to work! I'd still enjoy knowing why it doesn't work on my main drive, but at least I can work in the meantime.

Comment: I just update the moving folder to the answer. Glad it works on yours!

Comment: Issues - it can run now, but it seems that opening the designer view in both Visual Studio and Blend still give UnauthorizedAccessExceptions. Still some permission issues it seems.